# Visualization of citation data

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there any usable dynamical graph visualization of bibliographic (citation) data? That is:

- a map of papers (e.g. from Google Scholar or arXiv) connected by lines if one cites another (or in another variant - if they share a common author).

I found over the Net a few static visualizations:

- [Zotero Firefox plugin for Visual Understanding Environment](https://vue-forums.uit.tufts.edu/posts/list/521.page)
- [CiteSpace](http://cluster.cis.drexel.edu/~cchen/citespace/)
- [Thesis visualization](http://longair.net/blog/2009/10/21/thesis-visualization/)

There are dynamical ones:

- [PaperCube by Peter Bergstrom](http://papercube.peterbergstrom.com/) (it's a pity the program is working only on a demo database, the sole arXiv database would be great)
- [Web of Science - Citation map](http://images.isiknowledge.com/WOK46/help/WOS/h_citation_map.html) (nice, but for seeing not exploring + only for WOS)

Do you know/use/develop other graph visualizers of the citation data?

Comment: I do not have any positive reply to your request, however this news from march 2012 describe something close to what you are looking for. http://www.elsevier.com/about/press-releases/science-and-technology/dynamic-visualizer-of-research-footprints-wins-elseviers-application-development-challenge-in-china Does anybody has an other solution please?